# Are there any freely available tools for English Native Language Identification?

Tags: reference-request, resource-request, language-identification, native-language

I know that native language identification is a current research topic in natural language processing. I have an English text whose author clearly is not a native English speaker (I am not, either), and I feel that the author may be Russian. I would like to find some evidence for this feeling without sharing this text with others, if possible. Can I do this using freely available (online) tools?

Comment: Can you? Yes. Can you easily? ... You could collect a large sample of tagged text (English written by Russians, English written by English speakers) and construct some fairly straightforward python to do binary classification model. But as a convenient online app? I don't think so. Your quickest solution: find the exact English solecisms, and see if you can identify the native Russian grammar that would suggest such mistakes. E.g. does the text have a lot of dropped articles or copulas (missing 'the', 'a', or 'is' where expected)? Those are big Russianisms.

Comment: @Mitch: 'does the text have a lot of dropped articles': yes, that's what makes the think it's Russian. But what tells me it might not be Chinese, which is a language that does not have articles and might result in very similar appearance in English? Surely some people have already done the work you describe (collected text, constructed classification models - there is a couple of research papers on this), so I was wondering whether any of these results is readily available.

Comment: Any Slavic language will drop the articles, not just Russian.